# Set Visibility of a Spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, visibility

All- I have two spinners side by side. I want it to be so that if an item in spinner1 is selected, spinner2 is invisible and visa versa. In other words the user should only be able to select one spinner. Here is my code concerning the spinners:

```
 //Spinner 1
    List<String> spin1= new ArrayList() ;
    spin1.add("Select");
    spin1.add("1");
    spin1.add("2");
    spin1.add("3" );
    spin1.add("4");


    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.houses);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinnerlayout, spin1);


    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    //Spinner 2
    List<String> spin2 = new ArrayList() ;
    spin2.add("Select");
    spin2.add("1");



    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hotels);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinnerlayout, spin2);


    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Sample code welcome. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why did you vote my question down? I just want to know so I can improve future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is simple enough:

```
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position != 0)
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
    });
```

And vica versa for `spinner2`. You'll need to change the definitions of `spinner1` and `spinner2` so that they are visible to the whole class:

```
public class ... {
    Spinner spinner1;
    Spinner spinner2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        spinner1 = ...
```

Comment: When I ran it, spinner2 was not visible at all. With out me doing anything. (onCreate)

Comment: Ah, yes. When Spinners are built they select an item to display (by default position 0) which calls OnItemSelected... I updated my code for this, and this new approach gives the user a chance to switch back and forth between `hotels` and `houses`.

Comment: By the way, you can use `View.INVISIBLE` instead or `View.GONE` should that be a better fit for your design.